# When italicizing a noun to emphasize, italicize the article or not?

Tags: emphasis, italics

When I want to emphasize a noun by italicizing, do I need to italicize the article of the noun or not? For example, is this correct?

> "Is it an apple?"
>
> "No, it is *an orange*."

Or, is this correct?

> "Is it an apple?"
>
> "No, it is an *orange*."

A similar question for *the*.

> It is called *the curse of dimensionality*.

Or

> It is called the *curse of dimensionality*.

Comment: If you want to emphasize then probably just italicizing the word is best.  Italicizing the article as well suggests that you are referencing a "term".  But ultimately it's a judgement call -- italics are used for many things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because italicizing for emphasis can select any word as well as parts of words, italicizing an article means that you are emphasizing that article for some purpose. Compare:

> "Is it a orange?"
>
> "No, it is *an* orange."  (*An* emphasized in contrast to "a.")

---

> "Is it an apple?"
>
> "No, it is an *orange*." (*Orange* emphasized in contrast to "apple.")

Stylistically, it is better to omit italics if they aren't necessary for a given purpose, since emphasis is watered down with frequent use. That is one reason why both [MLA](https://style.mla.org/italics-for-emphasis/) and [APA](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/04/using-italics-for-technical-or-key-terms.html) recommend minimizing the use of italics for emphasis, and why more colloquial guides recommend against overuse ("[but don't overwork this device](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-iterative-verb-1691200)"). So there's no strict rule that demands you include the article, and an expectation that you have a deliberate reason for italicizing something. The rest is your decision.

Answer (score 1):

As a general guide, consider how you would *say the sentence out loud*. If you emphasise both the article and the other word(s), then put the article in italics:

> "No, it is *an orange*."

If (as would be more common) you instead find that you say the article with a normal voice but put extra emphasis on the following word(s), then *don't* put the article in italics:

> "No, it is an *orange*."

This general guide applies to just about any situation where you would say a particular word or words *louder* (see: that's an example) to *indicate emphasis* (there's another!). It's particularly useful in more conversational writing where you're trying to capture or replicate the non-verbal signals that spoken language includes, but as [TaliesinMerlin's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/494823/167396) notes, don't overdo it in more formal writing.